# Pyside6 QDoubleValidator - decimal places are not working as expected

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I have written the following PySide6 program and would like to limit the decimal places of the inputs.

```py
import sys

from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, QLocale
from PySide6.QtGui import QDoubleValidator
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QFormLayout, QWidget


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(420, 100))

        self.line_edit_2 = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_4 = QLineEdit()

        self.validator_2 = QDoubleValidator(0, 10, 2)
        self.validator_2.setNotation(QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)
        self.line_edit_2.setValidator(self.validator_2)

        self.validator_4 = QDoubleValidator(0, 10, 4)
        self.validator_4.setNotation(QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)
        self.line_edit_4.setValidator(self.validator_4)

        self.form_layout = QFormLayout()
        self.form_layout.addRow("Double 2", self.line_edit_2)
        self.form_layout.addRow("Double 4", self.line_edit_4)

        self.button = QPushButton('Validate')
        self.form_layout.addRow("", self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(
            lambda: {print(self.line_edit_2.hasAcceptableInput(), self.line_edit_4.hasAcceptableInput())})

        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.form_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But when I run it, no matter what I define in the third parameter (which, according to [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdoublevalidator.html#decimals-prop), controls the digits), I am not able to enter any doubles with decimal places greater than 2.

[image: non working validator example]

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question, I came up with the solution myself.
The problem lies in the language setting of the system. My system is set to german, but I tried to enter the floats in the international format with a dot. In order for the validator to use the correct decimal places when entering a dot, it must be set to the correct locale (if the system locale is different). For the example above I had to add the following lines:

1. Anywhere before the declaration of the line edits:

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QLocale
locale = QLocale(QLocale.English, QLocale.UnitedStates)
```

2. After each validator:

```py
self.validator_2.setLocale(locale)
```

```py
self.validator_4.setLocale(locale)
```

With these changes the validators work as expected:

[image: working validator example]